# Thymeleaf - How to handle the null value and assign different value based on the condition?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

In my case, the condition is if the **`question.objQuestion.questionContent`** is null, show the **`question.sbjQuestion.questionContent`**. My attempt is shown at below. But it doesn't work.

```html
<td th:switch = "${question.objQuestion.questionContent}"> 
    <span th:case="${question.objQuestion.questionContent == null}" th:text = "${question.objQuestion.questionContent}"></span>
    <span th:case="${question.objQuestion.questionContent != null}" th:text ="${question.sbjQuestion.questionContent}"></span>
</td>
```

[image]
**`obj_question_id`** and **`sbj_question_id`** are foregin id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I use the Elvis Operator **`?`** in this way

The solution is attached at below:

```html
<td>
   <span th:text = "${question.objQuestion?.questionContent}"></span>
   <span th:text = "${question.sbjQuestion?.questionContent}"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Elvis operator would be `?:`. This `.?` is usually called "null-safe navigation"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a [`th:switch`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#switch-statements), the `th:case` attributes should only contain the value to test.  In your case, it should look like this:

```
<td th:switch="${question.objQuestion.questionContent}"> 
    <span th:case="null" th:text="${question.sbjQuestion.questionContent}"></span>
    <span th:case="*" th:text ="${question.objQuestion.questionContent}"></span>
</td>
```

You could probably simplify this and just use the [Elvis operator](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator):

```
<td> 
    <span th:text="${question.objQuestion.questionContent} ?: ${question.sbjQuestion.questionContent}"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: I have tried ur code, it still show the error `Property or field 'questionContent' cannot be found on null`

Comment: So what you're saying is that `question.objQuestion` is null and not `question.objQuestion.questionContent`?

Comment: I have attach the database diagram in the question. As can seen from the screenshot, each question will have one foregin key depend on the question type. For example, if user create the objective question, subjective question key will be null. For my requirement,  I need that column to display the subjective question when the objective question is null. Vice versa, the column need to display the objective question when  the subjective question is null